# Connection diagram of external WatchDog timer MAX6369KA+T and Arduino

Tags: watchdog

**Tasks:**

1. Ensure a reliable reboot of the microcontroller in case of a hang.
2. The ability to disable the WDT timer.

For these purposes, I found an external watchdog timer [MAX6369KA+T](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6369-MAX6374.pdf).

**Scheme:**

[image]

**Logic:**

1. WDI is directly connected to the IO of the microcontroller, which will send short-term pulses (HIGH-LOW).
2. WDO is pulled to 5V through a 10K resistor. A 1K resistor is connected in series, which should protect the RST pin from static voltage. If no pulses arrive at the WDI from the IO of the microcontroller, the WDO should go down and cause the microcontroller to reset.
3. SET2 is pulled to VCC to start WDT. The MAX6369 can be turned off by pulling SET2 to GND. For this, I want to use a bipolar transistor, which can be controlled using a separate controller.

**Questions:**

1. Are there any errors in the circuit?
2. On WDO, I set the resistor to 1K in series. Will this affect the reset process?

Comment: Why do you have the resistor and transistor? From the looks of the schematic, the `IO_ARDUINO` will connect to the Arduino pin before the resistor anyway, since the nets are the same name.

Comment: Why can't you use the microcontroller's internal WDT?

Comment: This should be a fairly reliable device, so an external WDT is used here.
In terms of the transistor - I need to be able to disable this timer, for this you need to connect SET2 to GND. In normal mode, SET2 is pulled up to 5V, which turns on this WDT.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to work though. According to the datasheet you are supposed to strobe `WDI` *before* you change SETx. Since you have WDI and SET2 on the same pins, you can't achieve that. `WDI` is supposed to be your "I'm alive" signal, and you should be able to strobe that *independently* of disabling the timer. You should not disable the timer to reset the watchdog. Also as a matter of your schematic, please make GND's point down, and positive voltages point up.